# SwiftUI: (Mac) how to fill list row background without white spaces

Tags: xcode, list, swiftui

I want to fill all the list row background with specific color, I made simple this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0 ..< 5) { index in
           VStack {
                Text("Placeholder")
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color(.orange))
        }
    }
}
```

but the result contains a white spaces around the row:

[image]

so,  how to fill all row background?

Answer (score 2):

Use this modifier on the list:

```
.listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
```

Comment: What version do you tested?

Comment: Beta 6, but remember: my App is on Mac not iPhone

Comment: Make sure to use it on each element of the list. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202421/swiftui-remove-space-between-cells

Answer (score 1):

If you want same color for all rows

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    List(0 ..< 5) { index in
       ......
    }
    .colorMultiply(.orange)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: unbelievable. I was looking for hours to find a solid clean solution and this one actually works. No hacks, it just works. Thx!

To make it clear, the color on mulitply must be the same as the background below it or the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that works (in beta 6, since `.listRowInsets()` seems to be broken), but doesn't feel like a very good answer. You can use negative padding to force the background to draw outside of the list row (you might need to fiddle with the values a bit):

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    List(0 ..< 5) { index in
       VStack {
            Text("Placeholder")
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color(.orange))
        .padding(.top, -6)
        .padding(.bottom, -6)
        .padding(.leading, -18)
        .padding(.trailing, -18)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Good temporary solution !